# How to check field value and compare using if in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

**XSD file:**

```
<xs:element name="Header">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="MessageHeader">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="demoName" type="xs:string" />
             <xs:element name="purpose">
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="purposeMessage">
                    <xs:complexType>
                      <xs:sequence>                               
                        <xs:element name="unit" type="xs:string" />
                      </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                  </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

I want to check whether the element `purpose` is present or not in input XML file.
If it's present then I want to take its value and if it's not then I want to ignore its value.

I tried below but it's not working.

**XSLT:**

```
<Header>
    <MessageHeader>
        <xsl:for-each select="field[@name= 'Header']/object[@class='com.demo.ttt.xml.MessageHeader']/field">
            <xsl:variable name="var:varValue" select="value/text()" />
            <xsl:if test="string($var:varValue) = 'purpose'">
                <xsl:element name="{@name}" >
                    <xsl:value-of select="$var:varValue" />
                </xsl:element>

            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </MessageHeader>
</Header>
```

**Input XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" standalone="yes"?>
<field name="Header">
    <object class="com.demo.ttt.xml.MessageHeader">
        <field name="demoName">
            <value class="java.lang.String"/>
        </field>
        <field name="purpose">
            <array class="com.demo.ttt.xml.purposeMessage" length="1" level="1">
                <object class="com.demo.cce.eai.condition.xml.purposeMessage">
                    <field name="unit">
                        <value class="java.lang.String">Z01</value>
                    </field>                        
                </object>
            </array>
        </field>
    </object>    <!-- added by edit -->
</field>         <!-- added by edit -->
```

purposeMessage is array having multiple elements so i need to use one more for-each inside if condition how to do that?

expected output is -

```
<Header>
  <MessageHeader>
    <purpose><unit>Z01</unit></purpose>
  </MessageHeader>
</Header>
```

if purpose having multiple elements then it will create multiple elements inside

Comment: I added two closing tags at the end of the _input XML_ to complete the sample.

Comment: thank you why my if condition is not working and unable to check that string value and if value is there create and element ? any clue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following XSLT-1.0 solution will wrap the text value of the `<value>` child in a `<purpose>` element if the `@name` attribute of the `<field>` element has the value `purpose`. Each `<object>` will create an own entry as a child of the `<purpose>` element.

So the code will create the desired output not with a `for-each` but rather with a set of templates each matching a specific situation:

```
<!-- removes <field name="demoName"> from the XML -->
<xsl:template match="field[@name = 'demoName']" priority="1" />   

<xsl:template match="field" >
    <xsl:element name="{@name}">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:element>   
</xsl:template>     

<xsl:template match="field[value]" >
    <xsl:element name="{@name}">
        <xsl:value-of select="value/text()" />
    </xsl:element>   
</xsl:template>       

<xsl:template match="object[@class='com.demo.ttt.xml.MessageHeader']" >
    <MessageHeader>
        <xsl:apply-templates />  
    </MessageHeader>
</xsl:template>       

<xsl:template match="array" >
    <xsl:apply-templates />  
</xsl:template>
```

**Output is:**

```
<Header>
    <MessageHeader>
        <purpose>
            <unit>Z01</unit>            
        </purpose>
    </MessageHeader>    
</Header>
```

**EDIT:** changed whole template set.

Comment: but purposeMessage is also an array so i need one more for-each for all elements under purposeMessage.. ?

Comment: thanks but expceted output is - <Header>
  <MessageHeader>
    <purpose><unit>Z01</unit></purpose>
  </MessageHeader>
</Header>